# Parsing string with PHP to remove speicifc character

Tags: php, regex, string, trim

I have string in following formats:

ABC 318 XY2388

OR

ABC 318 XY02388

and I want them to become "ABC 318/XY 2388". So if there is any leading zero after the second batch of letters then remove them.

Using the following code I have managed to get the output as

ABC 318/XY 2388

ABC 318/XY 02388 **(Wrong!)**

```
$input = "ABC 318 XY2388";
$output = preg_replace("/([A-Z]*) (\d*) ([A-Z]*)(\d*)/","$1 $2/$3 $4", $input);
echo $output;
```

Can anyone please suggest a way that I can trim the 0(zero) out of there?

So if I pass following:

ABC 318 XY2388

OR

ABC 318 XY02388

Final output should be 
**ABC 318/XY 2388**

Comment: are 0's allowed anywhere or anywhere apart from the start ?

Comment: Yes 0's are allowed anywhere apart from the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` means "*repeated 0 or more times*", so you're making every single match optional. Your regex would even match the string `[SPACE][SPACE]` or `A[SPACE][SPACE]A` etc.

The regex `/([A-Z]+) ([0-9]+) ([A-Z]+)0?([0-9]+)/` would work much better.

Here's a [**demo**](http://regex101.com/r/zH4lQ5), and an autopsy:

- `([A-Z]+)` - *A capturing group matching the letters between A-Z repeated 1 or more times (that's what `+` means)*
- `[SPACE]` - *A literal space character*
- `([0-9]+)` - *A capturing group matching the digits between 0 and 9 repeated 1 or more times*
- `[SPACE]` - *A literal space character*
- `([A-Z]+)` - *The same as the first. A capturing group matching A-Z repeated 1 or more times.*
- `0?` - *A literal `0` character repeated 0 or 1 time (so it's optional).*
- `([0-9]+)` - *A capturing group matching the digits between 0 and 9 repeated 1 or more times*

[**PHP Demo**](http://codepad.org/pdT5qAED).

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $input = "ABC 318 XY2388";
    $output = preg_replace("/([A-Z]+) ([0-9]+) ([A-Z]+)0?([0-9]+)/", "$1 $2/$3 $4", $input);
    var_dump($output); //string(15) "ABC 318/XY 2388"

    $input = "ABC 318 XY02388";
    $output = preg_replace("/([A-Z]+) ([0-9]+) ([A-Z]+)0?([0-9]+)/", "$1 $2/$3 $4", $input);
    var_dump($output); //Same as above, as 0 is optional: string(15) "ABC 318/XY 2388"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a simple suggestion:  If what you need is to trim one or more in-the-middle 0s, maybe you can do:

```
$input = "ABC 318 XY0002388";
$output = preg_replace("/([A-Z]+) ([0-9]+) ([A-Z]+)(0*)([0-9]+)/", "$1 $2/$3 $5", $input);
var_dump($output); //should be "ABC 318/XY 2388"
```

Please note that I am saving the "in-the-middle 0s" on $4, but $4 is not part of the output.

I have not tested it, but it should work, maybe if you don't parenthesized the "(0*)", it works with "$1 $2/$3 $4" without saving the 0s.

I hope this helps.